# Why does the Excel Macro recorder code cause an error while execution

Tags: excel, vba

I've recorded a macro to change the title on a chart. Executing the macro gives me an Error 91 Object variable not set (Error 91).
How can I solve this as I'm running the same chart with different data, based on the clients selection, I need to change the title to inform the client what he requested.

Thanks beforehand

```
 Sub Macro9()
'
' Macro9 Macro
'

'
    Sheets("Grafiek Realisatie TFT").Select
    ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Select
    ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Text = "Projecten TFT afgewerkt tussen 0 en 100%!"
    Selection.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = _
        "Projecten TFT afgewerkt tussen 0 en 100%!"
    With Selection.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(1, 41).ParagraphFormat
        .TextDirection = msoTextDirectionLeftToRight
        .Alignment = msoAlignCenter
    End With
    With Selection.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(1, 41).Font
        .BaselineOffset = 0
        .Bold = msoTrue
        .NameComplexScript = "+mn-cs"
        .NameFarEast = "+mn-ea"
        .Fill.Visible = msoTrue
        .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
        .Fill.Transparency = 0
        .Fill.Solid
        .Size = 18
        .Italic = msoFalse
        .Kerning = 12
        .Name = "+mn-lt"
        .UnderlineStyle = msoNoUnderline
        .Strike = msoNoStrike
    End With
    ActiveChart.ChartArea.Select
    ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Select
    Selection.Left = 164.54
    Selection.Top = 7
    ActiveChart.ChartArea.Select
End Sub
'''
```

Comment: Maybe `ActiveChart` is `Nothing`. Macro recorder code can be useful as a starting point, but it normally needs rewritten to be robust.

Comment: Instead of `ActiveChart` name the exact chart you are trying to edit, like `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Grafiek Realisatie TFT").ChartObjects("Name of the Chart Goes Here")`. You can also use the numerical index instead of a written name `ThisWorkbook.Sheets(3).ChartObjects(1)`. I would suggest saving it to a variable for ease-of-use within your code. Then you can just do something like `MyChart.ChartTitle.Text = "Projecten TFT ..."`

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to use an object (i.e. a variable which is of the “Object” type) that was never created using the "Set" command before (in other words, that has no object (properly) assigned to it).

*That's what is saying the official documentation from Microsoft for the [Error 91](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/object-variable-not-set-error-91).*

Try to situate a chart variable right before the code recorded/generated by Excel so you can test the `Nothing` before using it :

##### VBA code :

```
 Sub Macro9()
'
' Macro9 Macro
'
    Dim chr As Chart
    Set chr = ActiveChart
    
    Sheets("Grafiek Realisatie TFT").Select
    
    If chr Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "The chart was not found!"
    
    Else

    chr.ChartTitle.Select
    chr.ChartTitle.Text = "Projecten TFT afgewerkt tussen 0 en 100%!"
    Selection.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = _
        "Projecten TFT afgewerkt tussen 0 en 100%!"
    With Selection.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(1, 41).ParagraphFormat
        .TextDirection = msoTextDirectionLeftToRight
        .Alignment = msoAlignCenter
    End With
    With Selection.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(1, 41).Font
        .BaselineOffset = 0
        .Bold = msoTrue
        .NameComplexScript = "+mn-cs"
        .NameFarEast = "+mn-ea"
        .Fill.Visible = msoTrue
        .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
        .Fill.Transparency = 0
        .Fill.Solid
        .Size = 18
        .Italic = msoFalse
        .Kerning = 12
        .Name = "+mn-lt"
        .UnderlineStyle = msoNoUnderline
        .Strike = msoNoStrike
    End With
    chr.ChartArea.Select
    chr.ChartTitle.Select
    Selection.Left = 164.54
    Selection.Top = 7
    chr.ChartArea.Select

    End If

End Sub
'''
```

You can also test `If ActiveChart Is Nothing` without creating a variable, as per [BigBen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9245853/bigben).

```
 Sub Macro9()
'
' Macro9 Macro
'

    Sheets("Grafiek Realisatie TFT").Select
    
    If ActiveChart Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "The chart was not found!"
    
    Else

    ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Select
    ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Text = "Projecten TFT afgewerkt tussen 0 en 100%!"
    Selection.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = _
        "Projecten TFT afgewerkt tussen 0 en 100%!"
    With Selection.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(1, 41).ParagraphFormat
        .TextDirection = msoTextDirectionLeftToRight
        .Alignment = msoAlignCenter
    End With
    With Selection.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(1, 41).Font
        .BaselineOffset = 0
        .Bold = msoTrue
        .NameComplexScript = "+mn-cs"
        .NameFarEast = "+mn-ea"
        .Fill.Visible = msoTrue
        .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
        .Fill.Transparency = 0
        .Fill.Solid
        .Size = 18
        .Italic = msoFalse
        .Kerning = 12
        .Name = "+mn-lt"
        .UnderlineStyle = msoNoUnderline
        .Strike = msoNoStrike
    End With
    ActiveChart.ChartArea.Select
    ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Select
    Selection.Left = 164.54
    Selection.Top = 7
    ActiveChart.ChartArea.Select

    End If

End Sub
'''
```